AWS Alerts for specific RDS event id
I have a necessity to be notified when RDS Storage autoscaler has triggered a pending scale storage task that will reach or exceed the maximum storage threshold.
In this documentation I have found that event "RDS-EVENT-0224" will fits perfect for this purpose.
Now I have a question: How to receive an alert or notification for only this specific event ?
Clarifications:
In RDS console there is only possible to chose an event type and event category, such as instance type and category "failure". But I would like to receive a notificattion only for one event_id which is RDS-EVENT-0224.
So maybe there some other way like set some alarms for specific event. Maybe there are also some examples of how to do this with terraform?
Thanks in advance!
I`ve found some information that its possible to use a custom event pattern with the EventBridge rule(first answer):
AWS Alert on RDS Cluster creation
But I can not found any valuable examples especially how to do this with terraform
